# How to change password for a key in polkadot.js

Tags: polkadot-js

Is it possible to change the passphrase of an account in polkadotjs web-browser plugin?

If the seed words are saved it is possible to import it again with a new password but if I export it to json and try to import it the password remains the same.

Is there any other known way of chaining it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't change the password for your json file. You can set a new password by re-importing the account using the mnemonics. But the password for unlocking the previously downloaded json files won't change.

Comment: Yes this confirms my observations.